# messagebodyreader jersey

Tags: java, web-services, jersey, jax-rs

I am making a java client for restful webservice and I want to send a string in request body.

This is my class.

```
 public class params {
    private String test;

  public String getTest() {
    return test;
  }

  public void setTest(String test) {
    this.test = test;
  }
```

and this is my main function class.

```
 public class testclient implements MessageBodyReader<params> {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ClientConfig config = new DefaultClientConfig();
        Client client = Client.create(config);
        WebResource service = client.resource(getBaseURI());
        params pobj = new params();
        pobj.setTest("myname");
        System.out.println(service.path("interface").post(params.class);
     }

      private static URI getBaseURI() {
        return UriBuilder.fromUri("http://localhost:8080/ivrservices").build();
      }

    public boolean isReadable(Class<?> params, Type genericType, Annotation[] arg2,
            MediaType arg3) {
        return false;
    }

    public params readFrom(Class<params> arg0, Type arg1,
            Annotation[] arg2, MediaType arg3,
            MultivaluedMap<String, String> arg4, InputStream arg5)
            throws IOException, WebApplicationException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
}
```

what argument do i pass in default functions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you totally misread **MessageBodyReader** usage. It is to be implemented by **Provider** not by client. For your case no custom provider is needed. For instance, you can use Jackson Json provider with POJO feature to send/receive **params**.
So, you client configuration would be:

`ClientConfig cc = new ClientConfig().register(JacksonFeature.class)`

 This will serialize **params** to Json.
Don't forget to register **JacksonFeature** on server as well to de-serialize request.

If you want to send **test** string only you don't need to wrap it. String is default entity type in **Jersey**.